# Can a toilet be above a vertical drop?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

Installing a new toilet on the second floor, would like to position it above the vertical drop installed in a chase. Can a toilet be placed directly above drop like this? I am not asking about venting.

[image: sketch of Plumbing]

Comment: But venting is what makes the difference. If the vertical drop serves as a vent, now, you need a **different** vent for everything below, because it's not a vent then. If it's not a vent, bombs away...

Comment: It's not a vent the vent is off the vertical shaft by a TY connector.

Comment: What is at the bottom of the vertical drop?

Comment: US the bottom is a long 90 elbow that then goes and connects to the rest of the home's sewage system.

Comment: But does the system below vent THROUGH the vertical pipe, to the vent off to the side, or is there a separate dry vent for the system below? If the system below is using the vertical pipe to connect to the vent shown, that **has** to be changed.